# JMH puzzle: StringBuilder vs StringBand

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I am having hard time to understand what is going on with this benchmark. I want to measure how my sample class `StringBand` works in comparison to `StringBuilder`. The idea with `StringBand` is to concatenate strings at the `toString()`, not on the `append()`.

### Sources

Here is the `StringBand` source - stripped down for benchmark:

```
public class StringBandSimple {

private String[] array;
private int index;
private int length;

public StringBandSimple(int initialCapacity) {
    array = new String[initialCapacity];
}

public StringBandSimple append(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = StringPool.NULL;
    }
    if (index >= array.length) {
        //expandCapacity();
    }
    array[index++] = s;
    length += s.length();
    return this;
}

public String toString() {
    if (index == 0) {
        return StringPool.EMPTY;
    }

    char[] destination = new char[length];
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        String s = array[i];
        int len = s.length();
        //char[] chars = UnsafeUtil.getChars(s);
        //System.arraycopy(chars, 0, destination, start, len);
        s.getChars(0, len, destination, start);
        start += len;
    }
    return new String(destination);
}
}
```

This code uses: `UnsafeUtil.getChars()` to actually get `String` char[] without copying, see the code [here](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-core/src/main/java/jodd/util/UnsafeUtil.java). We can also use `getChars()` and its still the same.

Here is the JMH test:

```
@State
public class StringBandBenchmark {

String string1;
String string2;

@Setup
public void prepare() {
    int len = 20;
    string1 = RandomStringUtil.randomAlphaNumeric(len);
    string2 = RandomStringUtil.randomAlphaNumeric(len);
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public String stringBuilder2() {
    return new StringBuilder(string1).append(string2).toString();
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public String stringBand2() {
    return new StringBandSimple(2).append(string1).append(string2).toString();
}

}
```

### Analyses

Here is my understanding of what is going on when adding two strings of 20 chars.

#### StringBuilder

- `new char[20+16]` is created (36 chars)
- `arraycopy` is called to copy 20 `string1` chars to `StringBuilder`
- before second appending, `StringBuilder` expands the capacity, since 40 > 36
- therefore, `new char[36*2+2]` is created
- `arraycopy` of 20 chars to new buffer
- `arraycopy` of 20 chars to append sencond `string2`
- finally, `toString()` returns `new String(buffer, 0, 40)`

#### StringBand

- `new String[2]` is created
- both appending just keep strings in the internal buffer, until `toString()` is called
- `length` is incremented twice
- `new char[40]` is created (total length of resulting string)
- `arraycopy` of 20 first string chars (`UnsafeUtil` provides real `char[]` buffer of a string)
- `arraycopy` of 20 second string chars
- finally, returns `new String(buffer, 0, 40)`

### Expectations

With `StringBand` we have:

- one less `arraycopy` - what is the whole purpose of doing this
- less allocation size: `new String[]` and `new char[]` vs. two `new char[]`
- plus we don't have many checks as in `StringBuilder` methods (for size etc)

So I would expect that `StringBand` works at least the same as `StringBuilder`, if not faster.

### Benchmark results

Im running benchmark on MacBookPro, mid 2013. Using JMH v0.2 and Java 1.7b45

Command:

```
java -jar build/libs/microbenchmarks.jar .*StringBand.* -wi 2 -i 10 -f 2 -t 2
```

Number of warmup iterations (2) is fine, as I can see that second iteration reaches the same performance.

```
Benchmark                                    Mode Thr     Count  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBand2       thrpt   2        20    1    37806.993      174.637   ops/ms
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBuilder2    thrpt   2        20    1    76507.744      582.131   ops/ms
```

Results are saying that `StringBuilder` is twice faster. The same happens when I eg rise the number of threads to 16, or use explicitly `BlackHole`s in the code.

**Why?**

Comment: First time listening to `StringBand`

Comment: Would be easier if you publish the minimized benchmark project. Is it possible?

Comment: Here it is, see updated question. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, as usual, "the owls are not what they seem". Reasoning about code performance by inspecting the Java code quickly gets weird. Reasoning by looking into the bytecode feels the same. Generated code disassembly should shed more light on this, even though there are minor cases where the assembly is too high-level to explain the phenomenon.

That is because platforms heavily optimize the code, at every level. Here is the hint where you should look. Running you benchmark at i5 2.0 GHz, Linux x86_64, JDK 7u40.

**Baseline:**

```
Benchmark                                    Mode Thr     Count  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBand2       thrpt   2        20    1    25800.465      297.737   ops/ms
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBuilder2    thrpt   2        20    1    55552.936      876.021   ops/ms
```

Yeah, surprising. Now, watch this. Nothing in my sleeves, except for...

**-XX:-OptimizeStringConcat:**

```
Benchmark                                    Mode Thr     Count  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBand2       thrpt   2        20    1    25727.363      207.979   ops/ms
j.b.s.StringBandBenchmark.stringBuilder2    thrpt   2        20    1    17233.953      219.510   ops/ms
```

Forbidding VM from string optimizations yield the "expected" result, as laid out in the original analysis. HotSpot is known to have the optimizations around StringBuilders, effectively recognizing the usual idioms like `new StringBuilder().append(...).append(...).toString()` and producing more effective code for the statement.

Disassembling and figuring out what exactly happened with the string optimization applied is left as exercise for the interested readers :)

Comment: Awesome! As soon as I rewrite the code to: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string1); sb.append(string2); return sb.toString();` the results are as expected. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you store more data in memory because of object overhead using this type of approach.

The reason of that performance issue might be this part

```
char[] chars = UnsafeUtil.getChars(s);
System.arraycopy(chars, 0, destination, start, len);
```

As there is not way to obtain the `char[]` from a String you must copy it to memory and then copy it back to `destination`.

What you could try is to replace it with

`s.getChars(0,len,destination,start)`

This give you access to `char[]` directly in `String` and pass it to `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Its possible to get the `char[]`, see the source of `UnsafeUtil`. Anyway, you are right that I can use `getChar` and still no difference.

Comment: The UnsageUtil not always return the char[] field. It require some over head because of reflection etc. What you can try is to run your bench with out the to string part and once again with to string and update the results.

Comment: I did that, as i've said, and no change. Still 2x difference. `UnsafeUtil` does not use reflection in a traditional sense.

Comment: @DamianLeszczyński-Vash UnsafeUtil does not use reflection (in any sense), and clearly demonstrates that there is a way to get the char[] out of the String...

Comment: @NitsanWakart. It does to access the Unsafe instance, but this is minor thing.

Comment: @DamianLeszczyński-Vash there's no reflection used in getChars()